# Interpolation issues between GeoTools and GeoServer (pixel shift/pixel origin?)

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, geotools, wcs

I found an unexpected behavior when trying to access a subset of a GeoTIFF in GeoTools and GeoServer.

I start with a landcover GeoTIFF that looks like this:

[image: original high resolution landcover]

I then resample the GeoTIFF (the local file using GeoTools and nearest neighbor interpolation) to have the same boundaries but 670x484 cols/rows, which results in (overlayed on the original):

[image: resampled GeoTIFF using GeoTools]

So far so good. Then I load the original GeoTIFF into GeoServer and make a WCS request that involves subsampling (but keeping the original data bounds). This is the call used:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/klab/wcs?service=WCS&version=1.0.0&request=GetCoverage&coverage=klab:original_geotiff&bbox=227558.0,1361997.0000999998,896858.0,1845597.0000999998&crs=EPSG:32628&responseCRS=EPSG:32628&width=670&height=484&format=GeoTIFF

The resulting GeoTIFF looks like this (I made sure that on GeoServer only the nearest neighbor interpolation would be available for the layer, even if it is anyways the default one):

[image: GeoServer WCS resampled]

This looks strange to me and I can only assume that it is bound to a different pixel origin handling, but then why would geotools not do the same?

As a crosscheck I also tried the exact same procedure with QGIS Server. And QGIS Server shows the exact same result as the locally resampled file, i.e. what I would have expected in first place.

Has anyone an idea what is going on here?